# ASP.net MVC return grouped list view

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Do I handle this in the linq or the View?
I have two tables: products and parts
Grouping products by productNumber which has many parts.

Ultimately I would like a view iterating through the rows to display:

Product Number, Product Description, Part PCS Total, Part PCS, Part Number, Part Description

So far, I got the viewmodel and something like:

```
var productlist = productvmlist.GroupBy(x = x.PartNumber).SelectMany(p => p).ToList();
```

But from there, I do not know how to get the sum of the pcs count grouped and display all the parts related to that product. Basically, Rows within rows.

Comment: Share your Products class and some sample input and output. You should not be doing all this in your View. View should only consist of display related code.

Comment: I was able to use this post to get me to where I needed to be: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376855/how-do-i-group-html-list-items-in-an-asp-net-mvc-view